# JUnit Parameterized Tests Dynamic Loaded List

Tags: java, junit4, parameterized-unit-test

I have a list of products, each of which have its own list of catalogues. The available catalogues are not the same for every product. I´d love to parameterize this Suite, in a way that testing each catalogue is a test case, but have until now only used static parameter lists, i.e.

```
@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")
public static Collection<String> catalogues() throws IOException, JAXBException
{
    return Arrays.asList(Products.getCatalogues());
}
```

where the catalogues are loaded from a config.xml file. If there is not other way, I´ll expand this solution to fit my need, but I want to know if there is a way to get to the place where the list is shown in the @Before and once there read the available catalogues and pass it to the @Parameterized.Parameters